# JavaScript/jQuery: How to Chain a Method that uses console.log()

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, chaining, method-chaining

I'm playing around with jQuery plugin development, and I'd like to chain methods. I read in the jQuery tutorial (https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) that you can chain methods by adding `return this;` to the end of the method, and that works for the first method (test 1). How can I do that for the second method (test 2), which uses `console.log`? Can all methods be chained?

```
   // test 1
    $.fn.greenify = function () {
        this.css('color', 'green');
        return this;
    };

    // test 2
    $.fn.console = function () {
        this.on('click', function () {
            console.log('hello world');
        });
    };

    $('a').greenify().console();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method should return the jQuery instance. The fact that the event handler uses `console.log` function has nothing to do with the returned value of that method. As `on` returns the jQuery object you can code:

```
$.fn.console = function () {
   return this.on('click', function () {
      console.log('hello world');
   });
};
```

Now the `console` method is chainable!

Comment: Is it possible to do it without jQuery?

Comment: What does `it` refer to? "How to Chain a Method that uses console.log()"?